# Elasticsearch Java High Level Client 7.3.1 :Aggregation for Index wise hits in search Response

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-7

I am using ES 7.3.1 and Elasticsearch high level client 7.3.1
We have an alias which comprises of 3 indexes.

```
Alias Name :  employee_search
Indexes in this alias : contract_employee,permanent_employee,client
```

I am searching over this alias as

```
SearchRequest searchReq = new SearchRequest("employee_search");
WrapperQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(searchQuery); //i am preparing a dsl query
SearchSourceBuilder sbb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sbb.query(qb);
searchReq.source(sbb);
SearchResponse resp = esClient.search(searchReq, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

In response I need an aggregation where I can get index wise hits (which index gave how many hits?)
Aggregation which needs to be implemented is

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "index_wise_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I implement this in the existing search response?

What I tried but did not work:

```
SearchRequest searchReq = new SearchRequest("employee_search");
    WrapperQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(searchQuery); //i am preparing a dsl query
    SearchSourceBuilder sbb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sbb.query(qb);
    sbb.aggreagation(AggregationBuilders.terms("index_wise_count").field("index"));
    searchReq.source(sbb);
    SearchResponse resp = esClient.search(searchReq, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: any help would be of great.

Answer (score 0):

i was missing an underscore :(

```
sbb.aggreagation(AggregationBuilders.terms("index_wise_count").field("_index"));
```